# Mathematica can't Simplify[Log[4]/Log[2]]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I `Simplify[Log[4]/Log[2]]` in Mathematica, it comes back 
unchanged. How do I coerce Mathematica into giving back `2`?

`Log2[4]` yields 2 as expected, but `Log2[x]` yields `Log[x]/Log[2]`, 
suggesting Mathematica is doing something unusual here.

Comment: Most of the top users have migrated over to [mathematica.se]. You may wish to check it out as we are about to graduate out of beta. Also, I don't see anything particularly unusual about `Log[x]/Log[2]` as it is formally correct and implies that `Log` is using another base, base `E` in this case.

Comment: Because if Log2[x] goes to Log[x]/Log[2], then Log2[4] should go to Log[4]/Log[2], where it would stop because Mathematica doesn't simplify that. In reality, Log2[4] goes to 2, suggesting some simplification is occurring.

Comment: Right, some does occur, but it can't simplify `Log2[x]` as `x` is indeterminate.

Comment: No, the point is that it DOES simplify Log2[x].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FullSimplify`:

```
FullSimplify[Log[4]/Log[2]]
```

> 2

Comment: Thanks! This works and doesn't rely on numerical approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
Simplify[Log[4]/Log[2]] // N
```

> 2.

Comment: Simplify[] doesn't do anything here; you get the same result without it.

Comment: @stevenvh I'm not certain, but I think the questioner was predicating this on the use of `Simplify`.